# Google Apps Script counting number of identical cells in 2 columns

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

So Im have 2 columns in google spreadsheet, A and B, and I want to compare them row by row (A1 to B1, A2 to B2, etc), and finally count the number of cells that has the exact same value (can be a string or integer, but have to be identical) and put it in another cell, D1 for example. This  is what I got so far, but it doesnt seem to do anything, and doesnt return any error either.

```
function compare() {
    var sss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var ss = sss.getSheetByName('theSheetINeed');
    var range1 = ss.getRange('A1:A'); //the first column
    var data1 = range1.getValues();
    var range2 = ss.getRange('B2:B'); //the second column
    var data2 = range2.getValues();
    var count = []; //to count the number of match
    for(var i =0;i 'smaller than' data1.length; i++){ //somehow i cant use '<'
        var abc = data1[i];
        var def = data2[i];
        if(abc == def){
            count += count;
        };
    };
    ss.getRange('D1').setValue(count.length);
}
```

Edit: so my code actually does something, it returns 0 everytime...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Modification points :

- Values retrieved by `getValues()` are 2 dimensional array.
- `count` is defined as an array. But it is not used as array.
- `i 'smaller than' data1.length` is `i<data1.length`.
- Starting row for column A and B are 1, 2, respectively.
- Cells without values are included. So when such cells each other are compared, the values become the same. (If you want to compare such cells, please remove `&& abc && def` from following script.)

### Modified script :

Your script can be written by modifying above points as follows.

```
function compare() {
  var sss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ss = sss.getSheetByName('theSheetINeed');
  var range1 = ss.getRange('A1:A'); //the first column
  var data1 = range1.getValues();
  var range2 = ss.getRange('B2:B'); //the second column
  var data2 = range2.getValues();
  var count = []; //to count the number of match
  for(var i=0; i<data1.length-1; i++){ //somehow i cant use '<'
    var abc = data1[i][0];
    var def = data2[i][0];
    if(abc == def && abc && def){
      count.push(abc);
    };
  };
  ss.getRange('D1').setValue(count.length);
}
```

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

Comment: This will work fine in my case, thanks. But it seems to ignore any numerical values, not just empty cells. Im just curious if there is a way to account for numbers too.

Comment: @User9123 I updated the script just now.  I modified from ``if(abc == def && isNaN(abc) && isNaN(def)){`` to ``if(abc == def && abc && def){``. Please confirm it.

Comment: @User9123 I'm glad I could be of help.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to an Apps Script needing to run in the background you can do this with out-of-the-box formulas, and therefore the result is live

```
=SUM(
   QUERY(
     FILTER(A1:B,A1:A<>"",A1:A<>0),
     "Select count(Col1)
        Where Col1=Col2 
        Group By Col1 
        Label count(Col1) ''"
     ,0)
 )
```

The advantage of formula based solutions is that they are more visible, and anyone following you can be sure the answer is correct without knowing they have to run a script to achieve this.

Breaking the formula down and starting in the middle:

```
FILTER(A1:B, A1:A<>"", A1:A<>0)
```

this returns all the rows where there is a non-empty cell. I do this because `QUERY` can be misleading with finding blank cells

```
"Select count(Col1)
    Where Col1=Col2 
    Group By Col1 
    Label count(Col1) ''"
```

This does the comparisons you asked for and returns a count for each of the values in A that have a match in B. The `Select` here uses `Col1` instead of `A` because the `FILTER` returns an Array not a 
Range.

From then the `SUM` adds up each of those totals.